How does ordinal multiplication actually work?
I understand the definition of multiplication, but I'm not entirely 100% sure on the method of manually computing it. For example, let $
\alpha = \{0,1,2\},$ and $\beta=\{0,1,2\}$.
Then, since $$\alpha\cdot\beta = \bigcup_{\delta<\beta}\alpha\cdot\delta,$$
does that mean that the resulting set is $\{0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2\}$, for a cardinality of $9$?
Thanks in advance!
EDITED TO FIX DEFINITIONS OF $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Neither $\alpha$ nor $\beta$ are ordinals, so you cannot apply the definition.  In set theory all ordinals include $0$.

That's  the definition for the case where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

From Wikipedia: "For $\beta > 0,$ the value of $\alpha \cdot \beta$ is the smallest ordinal greater than or equal to $(\alpha \cdot \delta) + \alpha$ for all $\delta < \beta.$"
